# Download files from database and saving them with different names

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm new in java, and I have several rows in my application and a download button in every row...but as you can see with this FileOutputStream line I'm able to save the file with that name MyPdf.pdf in that directory Downloads...when I click download button the first file is stored.
The problem is when I download a new file the old one is replaced, Is there any solution for this

OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\Downloads\MyPdf.pdf");

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the dynamic name while creating the file. Instead of hard-coding the file name you can use some dynamic options like saving file name with date stamp, so every time you download the file, it gets a different name.

you can do as below:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
String filename = "C:\Downloads\MyPdf_"+ timeStamp +".pdf";
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename );
```